# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.isTerracottaClustered()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

Hi I am new to Spring and trying it for past few days.It was worked for me initially but now i am getting an error. can someone please help. I am using Spring 3.1. and Hibernate 4.1.1
Error i get:

```
   Mar 15, 2013 1:47:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoginAction] in context with path [/OLS] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'estimatesDAOImp': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.imp.EstimatesDAOImp.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.isTerracottaClustered()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.beginingservlets.LoginAction.doPost(LoginAction.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.imp.EstimatesDAOImp.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.isTerracottaClustered()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.isTerracottaClustered()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration.isTerracottaClustered()Z
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.util.HibernateUtil.validateEhcache(HibernateUtil.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.getCache(AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.<init>(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.
beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 43 more
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dao.imp,com.dao.interfaces,com.service.imp,com.service.interfaces" />

    <bean id="userBo"  class="com.service.imp.UserBoImp">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="userDAO" class="com.dao.imp.UserDAOImp">

        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>

        </bean>



    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="classpath:/com/hibernate/config/db.properties"
    />



    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/niksuites"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="newgmail"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> <!-- LocalSessionFactoryBean 4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean-->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" > <!-- <ref bean="dataSource" />  --> </property>

        <property name="configLocation">

        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>




        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>  
           <!--  <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache-entity.xml</prop>  -->
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 

    </beans>
```

Comment: What is your hibernate.cache.region.factory_class in hibernate.cgf.xml?

Answer (score 5):

There should be more than one classes with the name `net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration` in your application's classpath. And the wrong one is found first. To resolve this, please search for `net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration` in your application's classpath. You can use [JFind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfind/?source=dlp) for this task. And then check one by one to find out which one is your expectation. You can use [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) for this task. Finally manage your dependencies carelly.

After googling, it seems that is a common issue. Hope [this mail](http://marc.info/?l=jboss-user&m=132524772514441) can help you.

In your configuration, do not use the new property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

but the old one:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem where a class was loaded multiple times. This might come from having multiple versions of the same class on your class path. In my case it was the `net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration` being loaded twice, once from my tomcat's lib folder and once from my applications lib folder.

To check where and how many times a class is loaded, start your VM with

```
-verbose:class
```

This will print all classes being loaded as well as the location on your file system.

You then should remove any duplicates of this particular class either by fixing your dependency problems or by removing any offending jars. It might also turn out that you have different versions of the `ehcache` library in which case you need to work on that problem first. If you post more details about how many times the class is loaded and from where we might be able to provide more detailed instructions on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am loading ehcahe and ehcahe-core so I removed ehcahce. Then the exception disappeared and exclude the ehcache-core as like below. please ensure you should not have ehcache dependency in your pom. Please refer [this](https://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/hibernate-4-and-ehcache-higher-than-2-4-3/) link for more:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```